# overlaying a div over three floats

Tags: html, css

I need a bit of help overlaying a `<div>` over 3 other `<div>` elements which are styled `float:left` in their own container.

It looks like this now (https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0dJb.jpg) and i would like the text to overlay on top of the three floated colorlines.

Here's my hmtl/css any help would be appreciated.

### HTML

```
<body>  

<div id="introtextcontainer">
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
<div id="linecontainer">
    <div id="line1">
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
#introtextcontainer {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px ;
    text-align:center;
    font-color: black;
    float:middle;
}

#linecontainer {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 3000px ;
}

#line1 {
    width:160px;
    height:2000px;
    background-color: #00A7B0;
    float:left;
}

#line2 {
    width:160px;
    height:2000px;
    background-color: #D1DE3E;
    float:left;
}

#line3{
    width:160px;
    height:2000px;
    background-color: #DE006B;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: where do you want to place text ?

Comment: Are you just using those three `<div>` elements for background-colors?

Comment: Also: it makes things easier for people who want to answer your question if you post all that code on http://jsfiddle.net - that way it's quick easy and convenient for anyone who wants to run or modify it.

Comment: gah! thanks a ton for all the tips/help/answers and without biting my head off for being a total newbie. I got it all fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just adding `position:absolute` and `width:100%` to your `introtextcontainer` container it seems to work:

```
#introtextcontainer {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VNmUD/1/)

Note that there is no such `float:middle;` property (left or right only).

Answer (score 0):

You could also position:absolute the #linecontainer to slide up behind the text (I also centered it with left:50%; margin-left:- 0.5 * width ). You might have to give the text a position:relative; z-index:1; to force it on top.

```
#introtextcontainer {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-color: black;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#linecontainer {
    margin: 0 0 0 -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 3000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
}
```

Or even better, use a gradient generator, remove the 3 divs and make the bars a background: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```
#introtextcontainer {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background: rgb(0,167,176); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,167,176,1) 33%, rgba(209,222,62,1) 33%, rgba(209,222,62,1) 34%, rgba(209,222,62,1) 66%, rgba(222,0,107,1) 66%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(33%,rgba(0,167,176,1)), color-stop(33%,rgba(209,222,62,1)), color-stop(34%,rgba(209,222,62,1)), color-stop(66%,rgba(209,222,62,1)), color-stop(66%,rgba(222,0,107,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,167,176,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 34%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 66%,rgba(222,0,107,1) 66%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,167,176,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 34%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 66%,rgba(222,0,107,1) 66%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,167,176,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 34%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 66%,rgba(222,0,107,1) 66%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,167,176,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 33%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 34%,rgba(209,222,62,1) 66%,rgba(222,0,107,1) 66%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00a7b0', endColorstr='#de006b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```